# Nodejs inserting data to mongodb. It takes too much time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Hi i am developing nodejs application. I am inserting data to mongodb but my page always in 'loading' mode. But strange thing is  my data inserted to mongodb immediately but page load not stopping. My code is shown below:

```
app.post('/Management/Post/New',function(req, res){
     new Post({
    title:req.body.post.title,
    body:req.body.post.body,
    keywords:req.body.post.keywords
  }).save(function (err, docs){
    if(err) {
         return res.render(__dirname + "/views/createpost", {
                    title: 'Yeni Gönderi Oluştur',
                    stylesheet: 'postcreate',
                    error: 'Gönderi oluşturulurken bir hata ile karşılaşıldı'
                });
    }
    console.log('Gönderi oluşturuldu');
  });
});
```

Have no idea.

Comment: Can you show us the client side code?

Comment: You're not sending/ending the response if there's no error.

Comment: You aren't handling the success scenario except for a console.log. You need a red

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only send a response when there is an error. If there's no error, you server never sends anything back: that's why the page seems to always be loading.

You need to send a response when you have no error, like this:

```
.save(function (err, docs){
    if(err) { // Executed when there was an error with Mongo
         return res.render(...);
    } else { // Executed when everything is fine
        return res.render(...);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't handling the success scenario except for a console.log. You need a res.render() or res.redirect() on success, not just error